# How to set up Wordpress in the intranet?

Tags: buddypress, localization, local-installation, customization

I have been looking for an answer for long time now and have tried on a few alternatives too, but still I am unable to do it.

What? : I want to set up Wordpress on the intranet in my workplace most likely using buddypress to set up a community. I just don't know how.

What are the restrictions at my workplace? : We don't have any access to the internet. Nothing. Its a super secure workplace (or so they want to make it). So I want a method to set up the whole thing using offline executables, preferably using open source frameworks/tools.

What have I tried doing till now? : I have tried using bitnami wordpress multisite. But I still fail to host the website for the public. Locally, it works fine. I am also acquainted with WAMP, but not sure how to host a website so that everyone can see it in the intranet using WAMP. I tried using IIS and found it supremely confusing. I found Windows platform installer that, as I read, does the work, but as I said, I have no internet connectivity at my workplace.

Can anyone suggest a way out to host a multisite Wordpress buddypress website on the intranet and help me move on from the stagnancy I have been for months now.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really WordPress-specific, if you search for WAMP intranet in Google, you will find info on connecting to WAMP from within an intranet, via the machine's IP or computer name.

Comment: as I said, I could not find the answer anywhere, and I think its a fairly Wordpress related topic, with scanty documentation.

Comment: Hire a consultant

Answer (score 1):

I recommend (and use myself) XAMPP located here [LINK](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), which will allow you to run a web-server on a machine of choice.

Once you setup XAMPP, you would install WordPress or WordPress with Multisite (enabled) just like you would any other WordPress installation on a website host.

You have full control over your server (run out of a folder of choice) and you also have full control over the MySQL server for which you need to create a database/username/password to give to WordPress during the setup process.

If you plan on having a machine that is always on then that's your best solution. I use and countless others do to, for local development.

XAMPP also comes with a handy control panel that sits in your system tray for which to control the server (start/stop Apache and MySQL);

[image: XAMPP Control Panel Application]

Comment: Hey thanks for the advise. I am going to give XAMP a try now. 

If you have already implemented the suggested set up, can you please guide me on how to set it up to be visible on the intranet, so that everyone can access the website?

Comment: No problem. This is where you'd need to get assistance from Stack Overflow questions/answers as this is a WordPress specific Q&A site. As a tip; you need to make sure that your computer is accessible on your network. I.e. your IP might be 192.166.0.1 - thus your firewall needs an exception that allows others to connect. There many, upon many guides online that will walk you through the process. Its rather simple to be up and running with XAMPP and the people over at SO will gladly help you out.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for this solution, but I could not find how to run Apache server on a LAN. If you restrict your site, you can use .htaccess IP block.

For example, if your IP is 10.5.215.27, you can access the site from your IP this way:

```
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from 10.5.215.27
```

Comment: The asker has a specified that his workplace has no internet access